# Secure way to accept SQL query via form input

Tags: sql

So I'm about to create a simple site where users can input their own SQL queries, which I will be running on the server side.

I'm aware of SQL injection attacks and assume this could be fairly risky thing to do.

But (if there is any) what would be a safe way to allow this feature?

e.g. I can think of the following rules I can enforce.

- Allow users to only "SELECT" - never allow UPDATE, DELETE (or anything else).
- Allow users to only access certain tables (if I know them).

Are there any other security measures I should take?

Answer (score 0):

As well as security issues, performance might be a problem as pointed out by ElectricLlama. You might want to look into getting the query's execution plan in advance, and refusing to run if it looks like the query would be too expensive:
[How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Answer (score -1):

Further to the above make sure the user is added to the `db_datareader` groups and that will make them read only. I guess you will be using a single user to perform that database actions.

You still cause a database failure if the user accidentally does a couple of cross joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1,Table2,Table3
WHERE Table1.Field1=Table2.Field2
-- Oops I forgot to enter the Table3 Join condition 
-- so now I get a cross join which will cause havoc
-- If the table is of appreciative size
```

But anyway it's still risky! Someone will find a security hole!